# Is there a way I can get these 2 dropdowns to "work together" to filter the table

Tags: javascript, dropdown, multi-select

Hi I've got a table that I wanted to filter using a custom JavaScript dropdown filter function. Separately they work perfectly, but the issue comes in when I try to use both at the same time to filter the table contents. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function searchUserName(input, tableName) {
        dropDown(input, tableName, 0);
    }

    function searchSupervisorName(input, tableName) {
        dropDown(input, tableName, 1);
    }

    var dropdown0 = false;
    var dropdown1 = false;

    function dropDown(input, tableName, colPos) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableName);
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var userDropdown;
    var userNamesArray = [];

    if (colPos == 0) {
        if (!dropdown0) {
            createDropdown();
            dropdown0 = true;
        }
    }
    else if (colPos == 1) {
        if (!dropdown1) {
            createDropdown();
            dropdown1 = true;
        }
    }

    function createDropdown() {
        if (!userDropdown) {
            userDropdown = document.createElement("div");
            userDropdown.id = "userDropdown";
            userDropdown.className = "dropdown";

            userNamesArray = Array.from(tr).map(row => {
                var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[colPos];
                if (td) {
                    return td.textContent.trim();
                }
            }).filter(Boolean);

            // Sort the user names alphabetically
            userNamesArray.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

            var userNamesSet = new Set(userNamesArray);

            // Add "Deselect All" option
            var deselectAllContainer = createOptionContainer("Deselect All");
            userDropdown.appendChild(deselectAllContainer);

            // Add separator line after "Deselect All"
            var separator = document.createElement("hr");
            userDropdown.appendChild(separator);

            userNamesSet.forEach(name => {
                var optionContainer = createOptionContainer(name);
                userDropdown.appendChild(optionContainer);
            });

            input.parentNode.insertBefore(userDropdown, input.nextSibling);

        } else {
            userDropdown.style.display = '';
        }
        removeOptionFromDropdown("null, null");
    }

    function removeOptionFromDropdown(optionText) {
        if (userDropdown) {
            Array.from(userDropdown.children).forEach(optionContainer => {
                var optionContainerText = optionContainer.textContent.trim();
                if (optionContainerText === optionText) {
                    userDropdown.removeChild(optionContainer);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function createOptionContainer(name) {
        var optionContainer = document.createElement("label");
        optionContainer.className = "option-container";

        if (name === "Deselect All") {
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.value = name;
            optionContainer.appendChild(checkbox);
            optionContainer.classList.add("deselect-option");
        } else {
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.value = name;
            optionContainer.appendChild(checkbox);
        }

        var optionText = document.createTextNode(name);
        optionContainer.appendChild(optionText);

        return optionContainer;
    }

    //showing dropdown onclick event
    function showDropdown() {
        if (userDropdown) {
            userDropdown.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function moveSelectedOptionsToTop() {
        var deselectAllContainer = userDropdown.querySelector('input[value="Deselect All"]').parentNode;

        var selectedOptions = Array.from(userDropdown.getElementsByClassName("option-container"))
            .filter(optionContainer => {
                var checkbox = optionContainer.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
                return checkbox.checked && checkbox.value !== "Deselect All";
            });

        if (selectedOptions.length > 0) {
            // Sort selected options alphabetically
            selectedOptions.sort((a, b) => {
                var textA = a.textContent.trim();
                var textB = b.textContent.trim();
                return textB.localeCompare(textA);
            });

            // Move all selected options to the top
            selectedOptions.forEach(optionContainer => {
                userDropdown.insertBefore(optionContainer, userDropdown.firstChild.nextSibling); // Insert after "Deselect All"
            });


        } else {

            // If no options are selected, move "Deselect All" to the top
            userDropdown.insertBefore(deselectAllContainer, userDropdown.firstChild.nextSibling);


            var allOptions = Array.from(userDropdown.getElementsByClassName("option-container"));

            allOptions = allOptions.filter(optionContainer => {
                var checkbox = optionContainer.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
                return checkbox.value !== "Deselect All";
            });

            allOptions.sort((a, b) => {
                var textA = a.textContent.trim();
                var textB = b.textContent.trim();
                return textB.localeCompare(textA);
            });

            // Move all options below "Deselect All"
            allOptions.forEach(optionContainer => {
                userDropdown.insertBefore(optionContainer, deselectAllContainer.nextSibling);
            });
        }
    }

    function filterTable() {
        var visibleRows = [];
        var searchValue = input.value.trim().toUpperCase();
        var selectedusers = Array.from(userDropdown.getElementsByClassName("option-container"))
            .filter(optionContainer => {
                var checkbox = optionContainer.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
                return checkbox.checked && checkbox.value !== "Deselect All";
            })
            .map(optionContainer => optionContainer.textContent.trim().toUpperCase());

        // Include all options if "Deselect All" is checked
        var deselectAllCheckbox = userDropdown.querySelector('input[value="Deselect All"]');
        if (deselectAllCheckbox && deselectAllCheckbox.checked) {
            // Uncheck all other checkboxes and remove selected options
            Array.from(userDropdown.getElementsByClassName("option-container")).forEach(function (optionContainer) {
                var checkbox = optionContainer.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
                checkbox.checked = false;
            });

            var deselectAllContainer = userDropdown.querySelector('input[value="Deselect All"]').parentNode;
            userDropdown.removeChild(deselectAllContainer);
            userDropdown.insertBefore(deselectAllContainer, userDropdown.firstChild.nextSibling); // Insert after the separator line

            selectedusers = [];
        }

        // Move "Deselect All" to the top after checking selected options
        moveSelectedOptionsToTop();

        Array.from(tr).forEach(function (row) {
            var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[colPos];
            if (td) {
                var userName = td.textContent.trim().toUpperCase();

                var matchesSearch = userName.includes(searchValue);

                var isInSelectedusers = selectedusers.length === 0 || selectedusers.includes(userName);

                var displayRow = matchesSearch && isInSelectedusers;
                row.style.display = displayRow ? "" : "none";

                var hasVisibleRowClass = row.classList.contains('visible-row-dp1');

                    if (colPos == 0) {
                        if (displayRow && hasVisibleRowClass) {
                            row.classList.add('visible-row-dp0');
                            visibleRows.push(row);
                        } else {
                            row.classList.remove('visible-row-dp0');
                        }
                    }
                    else if (colPos == 1) {
                        if (displayRow) {
                            row.classList.add('visible-row-dp1');
                            visibleRows.push(row);
                        } else {
                            row.classList.remove('visible-row-dp1');
                        }
                    }
                
                
                applyEvenOddStyling(visibleRows);
            }
        });

// Display "No matching records found" message if no visible rows
var dataTable = $('#maintable').DataTable();
if (visibleRows.length === 0) {
    dataTable.rows().nodes().to$().hide(); // Hide all rows
    dataTable.draw(); // Redraw the DataTable
    $('#maintable tbody').append('<tr class="no-records"><td colspan="colspan">No matching records found</td></tr>'); // Display no records message
} else {
    // If there are visible rows, redraw the DataTable and remove the no records message if present
    dataTable.rows().nodes().to$().show(); // Show all rows
    $('#maintable tbody .no-records').remove(); // Remove no records message if present
    dataTable.draw();
}



        Array.from(userDropdown.getElementsByClassName("option-container")).forEach(function (optionContainer) {
            var optionText = optionContainer.textContent.trim().toUpperCase();
            var displayOption = optionText.includes(searchValue);

            optionContainer.style.display = displayOption ? "block" : "none";
        });

        if (colPos == 1) {
            var SuperVisorSearchbar = document.getElementById("searchSupervisorInput");
            if (selectedusers.length > 0) {
                SuperVisorSearchbar.classList.add("selected-search-bar");
            } else {
                SuperVisorSearchbar.classList.remove("selected-search-bar");
            }
        } else if (colPos == 0) {
            var UserSearchbar = document.getElementById("searchInput");
            if (selectedusers.length > 0) {
                UserSearchbar.classList.add("selected-search-bar");
            } else {
                UserSearchbar.classList.remove("selected-search-bar");
            }
        }
    }

    function applyEvenOddStyling(rows) {
        rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
            if (index % 2 === 0) {
                row.classList.add('odd-row');
                row.classList.remove('even-row');
            } else {
                row.classList.add('even-row');
                row.classList.remove('odd-row');
            }
        });
    }

    userDropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
        filterTable();
        moveSelectedOptionsToTop();
    });

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
        filterTable();
    });

    input.addEventListener("click", function () {
        showDropdown();
    });

    document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if (userDropdown && !userDropdown.contains(event.target) && event.target !== input) {
            userDropdown.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    }
```

Since there can be multiple rows of a single supervisor, the supervisor dropdown will filter the table and the rows that are visible will be dynamically picked up by the username dropdown. Then, I can filter the username. The options in both dropdowns would also be multiselect and the table would be filtered accordingly. I also have an option open where the User can type out and filter either dropdown options and the separate columns they are in.

I will admit I used a lot of AI to help fix some bugs I had, so I might not be able to explain reasoning for everything but I'll try my best if you have any questions.

Comment: I assume you have the table data stored in an array. What's the filter criteria for the each of the drop downs?

Comment: yes they are stored in an array, and being displayed using the dataTables class. Filter criteria for dropdowns? i just took all the different names and if a name was already added i didnt add it to the dropdown list. but other than that there isnt any other criteria, i just removed null,null because some of the usernames where from outside the company of sorts

Comment: Please share an example of what your table looks like, and what your dropdown filters contain. If you can, it would help if you were to provide your the HTML markup, or better yet - create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read through all the filtering logic. I also don't know what the table data is.

To filter an array, you could use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the array object.

Say you have an array of students;

```js
let students = [
    {name: 'std1' , age: 23, sex: 'male'},
    {name: 'std2' , age: 29, sex: 'male'},
    {name: 'std3' , age: 25, sex: 'female'},
]
```

To get only male students, you would filter the students array like so:

```js
let maleStudents = students.filter((student) => student.sex == "male")
```

To filter the male students further say only male students less than the age of 26:

```js
let maleStudentsBelow26 = maleStudents.filter((maleStudent) => maleStudent.age < 26)
```

Or you could apply the sex and age filter at once on the students array:

```js
let maleStudentsBelow26 = students.filter((student) => student.sex == 'male' && student.age < 26)
```

You could then display the filtered array in your table.